# Advice on optimization, from personal experience or resource

Tags: javascript, performance

I have the below code that converts a giving input either text or string integer values, to an array with each digits as elements of the array.

Below is my implementation :

```js
function digitize(currentInput) {
  let arr = [];
  currentInput = parseInt(currentInput)
  return function divideRecursively(currentInput, arr) {
    let lastDigit = 0;
    let integerPath = 0;
    if (currentInput == 0) {
      return;
    }
    integerPath = Math.floor(currentInput / 10);
    lastDigit = currentInput - (integerPath * 10);
    currentInput = integerPath;
    divideRecursively(currentInput, arr);
    arr.push(lastDigit);
    return arr;
  }(currentInput, arr)
}

console.log(digitize(123));
```

I would need advice on optimizing the code and possible loopholes if any.

Comment: If you just need optimizing, you can instead ask the question in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the digits followed by a `parseInt` call to convert them from string to number :

```js
var input = '123';

console.log(input.split('').map(digit => parseInt(digit)));
```

Of course you can check if input is a number by using [`!Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) or surround the whole thing with a `try/catch`.